# Determining vector projection given angle between 2 vectors and components of one vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

(sorry if that is a dumb question, biochemist here)

I have a vector *v* projected onto a vector *u*. I know the angle between them and the components of vector *u*. Can I determine the magnitude of the projection of *v* onto *u*? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that any nonzero multiple of $v$ will have the same angle with $u$ but the magnitude of its projection onto $u$ will be different. Therefore this doesn't work if you don't have any further information about $v$.

Comment: Thanks @Jake28. It does make sense. After I posted the question, I realized that the magnitude of v is constrained, so when the angle is zero we have |v| = |u|, and when angle=-180, |v| = -|u|

From that, I believe I can just multiply u*cos(angle), which should give me the projection. Does that make any sense?

Comment: This makes sense if you assume that $v$ and $u$ always have the same magnitude.